# How to insert a column with the order in which the purchases were made using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following Data-frame with purchases:

```
[in]:

data = [[1, '01/01/2020',   'product_A'],
[1, '01/02/2020',   'product_B'],
[1, '01/01/2020',   'product_C'],
[2, '01/01/2020',   'product_A'],
[2, '01/09/2020',   'product_B'],
[3, '01/01/2020',   'product_C'],
[4, '01/01/2020',   'product_A'],
[5, '01/09/2020',   'product_B'],
[5, '01/01/2020',   'product_C'],
[5, '01/14/2020',   'product_A'],
[2, '01/09/2020',   'product_B'],
[1, '01/01/2020',   'product_C']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['client_id', 'purchase_date','product_name'])

df


[out]:

client_id   purchase_date   product_name
0   1   01/01/2020  product_A
1   1   01/02/2020  product_B
2   1   01/01/2020  product_C
3   2   01/01/2020  product_A
4   2   01/09/2020  product_B
5   3   01/01/2020  product_C
6   4   01/01/2020  product_A
7   5   01/09/2020  product_B
8   5   01/01/2020  product_C
9   5   01/14/2020  product_A
10  2   01/09/2020  product_B
11  1   01/01/2020  product_C
```

I need to add a column with the order in which each purchase was made.

I have manage brute force my way to do this using a for loop:

```
[in]:

df = df.sort_values(["client_id", "purchase_date"], ascending = (True, True))


first_client = df['client_id'].iloc[0]
first_date = df['purchase_date'].iloc[0]

purchase_order = []
purchase_order_index = 1

for index, row in df .iterrows():

  client = row['client_id']
  date = row['purchase_date']

  if client != first_client:
    first_client = client
    first_date = date
    purchase_order_index = 1

  elif first_date != date:

    first_date = date
    purchase_order_index += 1

  purchase_order.append(purchase_order_index)


df['purchase_order_index'] = purchase_order

[out]:

client_id   purchase_date   product_name    purchase_order_index
0   1   01/01/2020  product_A   1
2   1   01/01/2020  product_C   1
11  1   01/01/2020  product_C   1
1   1   01/02/2020  product_B   2
3   2   01/01/2020  product_A   1
4   2   01/09/2020  product_B   2
10  2   01/09/2020  product_B   2
5   3   01/01/2020  product_C   1
6   4   01/01/2020  product_A   1
8   5   01/01/2020  product_C   1
7   5   01/09/2020  product_B   2
9   5   01/14/2020  product_A   3
```

I have achieved the desired result, however, I know that using `.iterrows()` is not the best solution. I am sure there are solutions that are more efficient than that. I am trying to learn best practices with Pandas. Can anyone show me how to do this properly?

Clarification: the column 'purchase_order_index' shows the order in which purchases were made by every customer. To determine this order, I use the 'purchase_date' column. Purchases made in the same day count as a single purchase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [rank](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html), with `method='dense'`:

```py
temp = df.sort_values(['client_id', 'purchase_date'])
(temp.assign(purchase_order_index = temp.groupby('client_id', sort = False)
                                        .purchase_date
                                        .rank(method='dense')
                                        .astype(int))
)
    client_id purchase_date product_name  purchase_order_index
0           1    2020-01-01    product_A                     1
2           1    2020-01-01    product_C                     1
11          1    2020-01-01    product_C                     1
1           1    2020-01-02    product_B                     2
3           2    2020-01-01    product_A                     1
4           2    2020-01-09    product_B                     2
10          2    2020-01-09    product_B                     2
5           3    2020-01-01    product_C                     1
6           4    2020-01-01    product_A                     1
8           5    2020-01-01    product_C                     1
7           5    2020-01-09    product_B                     2
9           5    2020-01-14    product_A                     3
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you used .assign instead of just temp['purchase_order_index'] = temp.groupby('client_id', sort = False)
                                        .purchase_date
                                        .rank(method='dense')
                                        .astype(int))?

Comment: personal choice; I try not to modify the original `df`; it doesn't matter in this case though; either option should be fine, with the direct assignment usually faster

Comment: One last question, why do you set sort = false inside the groupby method? Is it strictly necessary?

Comment: `sort=False` is not strictly necessary, sometimes though it can offer performance boost